# Is it possible to inform the C# compiler that another property will be non-null based on another property?

Tags: c#, nullable, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types, c#-9.0

Supposing I have a class like this:

```
public class BridgeFormModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display( Name = "What is your name?" )]
    public String? Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display( Name = "What is your quest?" )]
    public String? Quest { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display( Name = "What is your favourite colour?" )]
    public String? FaveColour { get; set; }

    [BindNever]
    public Boolean IsValid =>
        !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( this.Name ) && 
        !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( this.Quest ) && 
        !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( this.FaveColour );
}
```

Currently the C# 8.0 and C# 9.0 compiler will not infer that `Name` is not-null when it knows `IsValid` is true:

```
public IActionResult CrossTheBridge( BridgeFormModel form )
{
    if( form.IsValid )
    {
        if( form.FaveColour.Equals( "Blue" ) ) // Warning: `form.FaveColour` may be null here
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "Right, off you go" )
        }
    }
}
```

So we have to either assert `form.FaveColour!` - or do this instead:

```
public IActionResult CrossTheBridge( BridgeFormModel form )
{
    if( form.IsValid && form.FaveColour != null && form.Name != null && form.Quest != null )
    {
        if( form.FaveColour.Equals( "Blue" ) )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "Right, off you go" )
        }
    }
}
```

---

We have the `[NullWhen]` and `[NotNullWhen]` attributes, but those only apply to method parameters, not other properties on the same object instance.

This wouldn't be an issue if C# still supported code-contracts, but alas, here we are... is there any way to inform the C# compiler of nullability (and other state-invariants?) based on a property?

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
public class BridgeFormModel
{
    [NotNullWhenPropertyIsTrue( nameof(IsValid) )]
    [Required]
    [Display( Name = "What is your name?" )]
    public String? Name { get; set; }

    [NotNullWhenPropertyIsTrue( nameof(IsValid) )]
    [Required]
    [Display( Name = "What is your quest?" )]
    public String? Quest { get; set; }

    [NotNullWhenPropertyIsTrue( nameof(IsValid) )]
    [Required]
    [Display( Name = "What is your favourite colour?" )]
    public String? FaveColour { get; set; }

    [BindNever]
    public Boolean IsValid =>
        !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( this.Name ) && 
        !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( this.Quest ) && 
        !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( this.FaveColour );
}
```

As `NotNullWhenPropertyIsTrue` is not a real attribute, I'm wondering if there's some way to write a Roslyn extension or analyser that can implement the necessary logic - or provide null-safety assertions to Roslyn.

Comment: Does it work when you have `this.Name != null` as well in the `IsValid` property to make it easier for the compiler to see the `null` check (and not hide behind `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`?

Comment: can you use `is`? `if( form.FaceColour is string colour && colour.Equals( "Blue" )) { Console.WriteLine(colour); }`

Comment: @Progman Yes, that works, but my point is that it shouldn't be necessary to do that.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Yes, and I demonstrated that in my question already - my point is that it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Dai I do not see you demonstrating that in your question....

Comment: `form is { IsValid: true, FaceColour: "Blue" }` would work too since it's all constants... Though I admit it's not what's being asked, I just like how it looks

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 When using the `is { Prop: value }` syntax, how do you specify an `IComparer`? or is it always bound to `Object.Equals(Object)` - or does it use `IEquatable<T>` if available?

Comment: @Dai unfortunately you don't, which makes switching on string constants semi-problematic for example. If they ever introduce active patterns (user defined `is` essentially) then it would become possible to specify a Comparer. But for now... You can't

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may look at [`MemberNotNullWhen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.membernotnullwhenattribute?view=net-5.0) attribute, which was introduced in C# 9 and .NET 5 and write something like this:

```cs
[MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(Name), nameof(Quest), nameof(FaveColour))]
public Boolean IsValid =>
        !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( this.Name ) && 
        !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( this.Quest ) && 
        !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( this.FaveColour );
```

Design notes and additional details can be found in the dotnet runtime [issue #31877](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31877)